# How does the 10th frame count towards a 'closed' game in bowling

Tags: rules, bowling

At my club we were discussing what a 'closed' game is.

A closed game is when you hae no open frames. The thing we couldn't agree on was the 10th frame.
Lets assume we have 9 strikes.

What if I throw a spare in the 10th and finally 9 pins. Is this considered a 'closed' game?

Or do I allways have to end with a strike/spare

Comment: Is "closed game" is a concepy you and you friends invented?

Comment: I have heared more people talk about it. Until now nobody was able to give me an exact answer on the 10th frame.

Comment: I'm familiar with this as a "Clean Game" but I understood that it sometimes refers as a "Closed Game"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Definition](http://bowling.about.com/od/bowlingglossary/g/g_patch.htm) to Closed Game, Also Known As: Patch or Clean game, is:

> (1) A game with no open frames. This comes from the pursuit of the
>   fictional USBC award patch for no open frames.
>
> (2) An award given out by the USBC for individual and team
>   accomplishments. Starting with the 2009-2010 season, the patches have
>   been replaced by magnets.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten-pin_bowling):

> A "Clean Game" is a game with strikes or spares in every frame (not
>   counting bonus balls).

or

> A single game of bowling where the player has a mark (spare or strike)
>   in all ten frames.

So according to this definitions the case you describe is in deed a "Closed Game" since you didn't left any open frames. the last 9-pins throw was part of the bonus shoot which isn't included in "Close Game" definition.

Here is a very similar [post](http://www.examiner.com/article/so-was-my-clean-game-really-clean) that present the same question with a little bit different scenario.